# Introducir un valor predeterminado a params

Tags: angularjs-2.0

quisiera poner un valor predeterminado en params['page'] para que nativeElement no me salga como undefined.

Aqui os dejo parte del código.[image: contacto.component.ts[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY3o8.png)

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido resolverlo, solo tenía que introducir la función que estaba dentro de `this._route.params.forEach((params: Params)=>{
            this.parametro = params['page'];
            console.log(params['page']);

```
    });
```

dentro de ngAfterViewInit(){}`